# Selecting same column twice with different conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a hard time reaching my goal in SQL. Spent hours reading through similar question here and elsewhere, but my problem seems unique.

My database is of several columns:

> client name || project || type || date || cost || correction 
>      Client1          Project1 
>    TV    2018-1  100        no 
>     Client1          Project1  TV    2018-1  -50        yes

So the table warrants some explanation. (It also has an auto_inc ID for every row.) Correction = no means that this is an original value, created when forecasting finances. 'Yes' means it is a later correction in prices.

My goal is to look at forecast and actual side by side. So for every month, it should sum up correction = no values (which is pretty simple with

```
SELECT date, SUM(cost) FROM table WHERE correction='no' GROUP BY date)
```

and then list all the actual values (which is just SUM without the WHERE clause).

Rows need to be matched based on client, project, type, and date. This seems pretty simple, but I've been getting single row errors, naturally. Logically I cannot find a solution on how to do this, and I'm more of a beginner-casual SQL user.

So I want:

- column with months,
- column with SUM(cost) WHERE correction='no',
- and a column with all costs summed, of course these all differentiated by months.

I would appreciate some input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation.

An aggregate function performs a calculation on a set of values and returns a single value.

conditional aggregation is an aggregation on a conditional expression, e.g. the sum of all costs where the `correction = 'no'`. This is done with a `CASE` construct inside the aggregation function (`SUM` here):

```
select 
  year(date), month(date),
  sum(case when correction = 'no' then cost end) as sum_no,
  sum(case when correction = 'yes' then cost end) as sum_yes,
  sum(cost) as sum_total
from mytable
group by year(date), month(date)
order by year(date), month(date;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a case like this, I like to break it down by using Common Table Expressions (CTEs).  This allows me to calculate the projected cost for each client/project/month and set that aside in one CTE, then separately calculate the actual costs in another CTE, then query from each of those results.

```
WITH projection AS (
    SELECT [client name], project, type, date, SUM(cost) cost FROM test WHERE correction='no' GROUP BY [client name], project, type, date
),
actual AS (
    SELECT [client name], project, type, date, SUM(cost) cost FROM test GROUP BY [client name], project, type, date
)
SELECT p."client name", p.project, p.type, p.date, p.cost AS "projected cost", a.cost AS "actual cost"
FROM projection p
JOIN actual a ON a."client name" = p."client name"
AND a.project = p.project 
AND a.type = p.type
AND a.date = p.date
```

Note: I used the following to build my test table and values:

```
CREATE TABLE test ([client name] VARCHAR(100), project VARCHAR(100), type VARCHAR (100), date VARCHAR(100), cost INT, correction VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project1', 'TV','2018-1', 100, 'no')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project1', 'TV','2018-1', 200, 'no')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project1', 'TV','2018-2', 300, 'no')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project1', 'TV','2018-2', 400, 'no')

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project1', 'TV','2018-1', -50, 'yes')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project1', 'TV','2018-2', -99, 'yes')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project1', 'TV','2018-2', -75, 'yes')

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project2', 'TV','2018-1', 10, 'no')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project2', 'TV','2018-1', 20, 'no')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project2', 'TV','2018-2', 30, 'no')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project2', 'TV','2018-2', 40, 'no')

INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project2', 'TV','2018-1', -50, 'yes')
INSERT INTO test VALUES ('Client1', 'Project2', 'TV','2018-2', -99, 'yes')
```

And my results:

```
"client name"   project   type   date     "projected cost"  "actual cost"
--------------- --------- ------ -------- ---------------- --------------
Client1         Project1  TV     2018-1                300            250
Client1         Project1  TV     2018-2                700            526
Client1         Project2  TV     2018-1                 30            -20
Client1         Project2  TV     2018-2                 70            -29
```